# How can I have a static_assert with only the error message?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++20, static-assert

When I use `static_assert` like so:

`static_assert(condition, error_message)`, the compiler gives me a bunch of errors + the error_message when the condition is not met. How I make it so that only the error_message is printed?

The reason I want to do this is because my c++ files would be computer generated and thus the compiler error messages would confuse the user.

I am open to other alternatives than `static_assert` as long as it prints an error message at compile time.

Comment: Please give a minimal reproducible example so we can see what you mean by "a bunch of error messages".

Comment: If the preprocessor can be used, you could use `#error`, but I don't really recommend that. I assume that the other errors are just a result of the failed compilation, which you'd probably be stuck with.

Comment: @NathanPierson It will say things like static_assert failed at line 42 etc... But the error messages vary from compiler to compiler.

Comment: @ChrisMM The preprocessor cannot be used because I need to emit error messages based on some constexpr template metaprogramming boolean values.

Comment: This would be compiler-specific, but I wouldn't guess that very many offer much control over the exact output.  Normally they would assume the message is for the benefit of the programmer, who would rather have more information than less.  You might need to filter the compiler output.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes perhaps the best way would be to redirect the error messages to a log file and then pick out my error messages... I hoped there would be an easier way. Do you know how to redirect error messages in a compiler independent, portable way?

Comment: No, all such things are compiler and/or OS dependent.  The C++ standard doesn't say anything more than "issue a diagnostic" and that it should *include* the text of the message. Nothing about how that should be done, where it should go, or what it should look like.  It's a question of your compilation process and not of the language itself.